# Function that transforms the interval $[a,b]$ into $[0,1]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone please give me an example of function that translates the interval $[a,b]$ into $[0,1]$

I tried $\frac{x-a}{p(x)}$ and after that $x(x+b-a-1)+a$.

Comment: what is your idea?? did you try anything?

Comment: You need to translate it and resize it. What functions do you know that do that?

Comment: yep. i tried (x-a)/p(x) and after that x(x+b-a-1)+a

Comment: What function takes $[a,b]$ to $[0,b-a]?$

Comment: well that is x-a

Comment: Then just divide it all by $b-a$.

Comment: yeah.thanks. i tried (x-a)/(x-b) but it was not good

Comment: @Patrick Next time, you should add things you tried in the post, otherwise your question will be downvoted. Also, you can express your thanks by accepting the answer, that means that you click the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot:D I am new to this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need $f(a)=0, f(b)=1, f:[a,b]\to [0,1]$ 
$f(t)=(x-a)/|b-a|$
Should do the trick, as long as $a\neq b$

Comment: if you assume wlog $b>a$ then you don't need the absolute value in the denominator

Comment: @YvesDaoust I guess it is somehow implicitly assumed that $b>a$ holds so $b-a$ is positive as well (and therefore everything works)

Comment: @user190080: this assumption is unnecessary, why complicate things when there is a simple general formula ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust you're completely right, it is not necessary to assume the above. I just wanted to give an explanation why the answer is still correct, further the notation $[a,b]$ inherits that $b>a$, so it really is not arbitrary to assume that, but then of course we don't need the absolute value...so all in all it is indeed overcomplicated and one better drops the absolute value!

Answer (score 1):

One nice way to think of this is by looking at it as a linear transformation.

You want

$$
f(a) = 0
$$
$$
f(b) = 1
$$

So, considering $f$ to be a line, with $f(x) = y$,

$$
y - y_0 = m (x - x_0)
$$

where $m$ is the slope of the line, $y_0$ and $x_0$ are known points. Since the slope of the line is equal to the ratio of the difference of the y and x axes at any 2 points, this gives us

$$
m = \frac{y_1 - y_0}{x_1 - x_0}
$$

where $(x_0, y_0)$, $(x_1, y_1)$ are known points on the line $f$.

substituting for $m$:
$$
y - y_0 = \frac{(y_1 - y_0)}{(x_1 - x_0)} (x - x_0)
$$

Since $ f(a) = 0 $ and $f(b) = 1$, this implies that $(x_0, y_0) = (a, 0)$ and $(x_1, y_1) = (b, 1)$

Plugging these values into the two point slope equation yields us

$$
y - 0 = \frac{1 - 0}{b - a}(x - a)
$$
$$
y = \frac{(x - a)}{(b - a)}
$$